# What story do "Flits", tiny, highly magical beings, come from?

Tags: story-identification, object-identification

What story do "Flits", tiny, highly magical beings, come from?

[My source](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/chapter/971826?comment=6825601#comment-6825601):

> Pixies sort of remind me of Flits from a book I once read, tiny but with extreme magic powers, not to be messed with but flighty and occasionally mischievous.

Comment: Why not ask @DOCSavage?

Comment: I don't see how this is answerable. A quick search on Goodreads has identified at least two books with "flits" that are essentially pixies; https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8695479-unshapely-things + https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/58375701-edie-and-the-box-of-flits

Comment: And that's from 30 seconds of looking. There's at least two more on Google Books

Comment: Neither of the Goodreads examples appear to match "extreme magic powers," so I'm voting to keep this open.

Comment: @Valorum - How did you do that search? Because it seems you found the answer! ... Also, I guess I didn't think to ask DOCSavage because if someone is already so vague with their info, "a book I just read", etc. It doesn't sound like they know anything useful either, but hey, I was wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Valorum, for your comment, bringing up [the first book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8695479-unshapely-things) of the [Connor Grey series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42290-connor-grey), which has gotta be it. Unless someone can find a similar series:

The first book's description includes:

> Connor Grey, a druid and former hotshot Guild investigator-whose magical abilities were crippled after a run-in with a radical environmentalist elf.

And my source [just](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/chapter/971826?comment=7983118#comment-7983118) chimed in with new info:

> It was an Urban Fantasy set in an alternate world. **The MC was once a rising star among mages before an accident made him crippled magically**, he still had lots of power but was unable to channel it easily. *Part of a series* actually, the last novel I read in the series he had helped set up an area outside the control of the corrupt mage's.